# Uploading huge no of files into S3 is very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading 1.8 GB of data that has 500000 of small XML files into the S3 bucket.
When I upload it from my local machine, it takes a very very long time 7 hours.

And when I zipped it and uploaded it takes 5 minutes of time.

But my issue is I can not zip it simply because later on I need to have something in AWS to unzip it.

So is there any way to make this upload faster? Files name are different not running number.
Transfer Acceleration is enabled.

Please suggest me how I can optimize this?

Answer (score 1):

You can always upload the zip file to an EC2 instance then unzip it there and sync it to the S3 bucket.

The Instance Role must have permissions to put Objects into S3 for this to work.

I also suggest you look into configuring an S3 VPC Gateway Endpoint before doing this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html

Comment: This is what i want to avoid ..I do not want to create any compute environment in AWS .

Comment: In that case have a look here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-optimize-transfer/

Comment: Yes i had look into that ..But i am looking not in between S3 bucket but between on prem data center  into AWS/S3 ..

Comment: Yeh that’s fine, that’ll just mean the source won’t be an S3 bucket but a local directory instead.

Comment: Yes this is what i am doing but it takes very very long time when i upload 500000 files but the size is only 1.7gb...More than 4 hours ...